# How to use 2 index.htmls in an angularjs application?

Tags: angularjs

In an angularjs application, is it possible to use a different (index.html?) for login page and use another index.html page for rest of the pages in the application?

Comment: Its possible but not by taking a pure angular approach to SPA.  I'd say that if you're trying to have more than one main page you have missed the point and power of a properly designed SPA

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, however you can also use `ng-if` on the login html code and the regular html code:

```
<div ng-if="userLoggedIn">
   <login page html>
</div>

<div ng-if="!userLoggedIn">
   <regular page html>
</div>
```

Which will show one of the divs according to what is set as $scope.userLoggedIn in your main controller.

Answer (score 0):

also you can use `ng-show` and `ng-hide`

```
<div ng-show="userLoggedIn">
   <login page html>
</div>

<div ng-hide="!userLoggedIn">
   <regular page html>
</div>
```

Comment: ng-show and ng-hide actually load the html and set display:none. This means that even if you are not logged in, the regular html page will still get loaded, then it will be hidden once the scope variables are set.